# Exchange 2013 get uniqueId of WellKnownFolderName

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

This might be stupid but i have been looking for this for a long time now and i still don't have any idea on how to do it.
my problem is that i got a folderId(which has no name but just the UniqueId) coming from an event and i want to know if this forder is the DeletedItems one.

when i call the methods :

```
new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems)
```

or

```
new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems, mailBox)
```

i just get a FolderId which name is set but UniqueId is still null, therefore i can't compare UniqueId, the method Equals also fail...
Btw, i working on exchange server 2013 with an impersonatedUser.

**Edit : I feel even more stupid as i finally found out how easy it was : ***

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(ewsInstance, WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems);
if (Equals(event.ParentFolderId.UniqueId, folder.Id.UniqueId))
```

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to your own question rather than as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly found the answer :

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(ewsInstance, WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems);
if (Equals(event.ParentFolderId.UniqueId, folder.Id.UniqueId))//...
```

Comment: Perfect. Now please click the check mark next to your answer to accept it. You'll even get reputation for it. :-)